# Fade in and out <div> elements via checkbox with javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

So, I want to fade in and out a `<div>` with a checkbox and jquery. The `<div>`, which should get faded in/out, has the id "jobstartdatefade". The checkbox-id is "jobfixedstart". The Browser gives back the error "Uncaught SyntaxError:
 Unexpected token ;"

Here is my javascript code:

```
            //Setting the checked status to false
            document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked = false;


            document.getElementById('jobfixedstart').onclick = function(){

            if(document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked == false;){
            $('#jobstartdatefade').fadeIn(200); 
            document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked = true;    
            }

            if(document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked == true;){
            $('#jobstartdatefade').fadeOut(200);    
            document.getElementById("checkbox").checked = false;    
            }
            };
```

The HTML code for the checkbox looks like this:

```
      <input type="checkbox" class="form-control" value="jobfixedstart" id="jobfixedstart" />
```

And the `<div>`, which should get faded in in html looks like that:

```
<div id="jobstartdatefade">Text<div>
```

Thank you

**Edit:**

This code works, without the toggle-method:

```
document.getElementById('jobfixedstart').onclick = function(){
$('#jobstartdatefade').fadeIn(200);
};
```

Jquery is linked properly - other jquery animations work.

Comment: just using javascript not jquery

Comment: I fade in the div-element with jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unexpected token is because of the `;` in this two lines `if(document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked == false;){}` & `if(document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked == true;){}`.

Also the `fadeIn` & `fadeOut` handlers need to be reversed.When the text box is checked it should `fadeIn` and vice versa

The `if` statement does not accept any semi colon

```js
document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked = false;
document.getElementById('jobfixedstart').onclick = function() {

  if (document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked === false) {
    $('#jobstartdatefade').fadeOut(200);
  }
  if (document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked === true) {
    $('#jobstartdatefade').fadeIn(200);

  }
};
```

```css
.fadeIn {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" value="jobfixedstart" id="jobfixedstart" />
<div id="jobstartdatefade" class="fadeIn">Text
  <div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('#jobfixedstart').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

try like this,,

```
<input type="checkbox" class="form-control" value="jobfixedstart" id="jobfixedstart" onclick="run();" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function run(){
        if(document.getElementById("jobfixedstart").checked == true) 
                {
                     document.getElementById("jobstartdatefade").style.visibility = 'hidden' ;
                }
                else
                {
                     document.getElementById("jobstartdatefade").style.visibility = '' ;
                }
 </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation :D - What is wrong? :D

Comment: :D, i dont know